# Looking for a way to test how often filesystem data is flushed

Tags: filesystems, embedded

I have an embedded system, which by it's nature, has power cut off with little warning to the system.  The system writes log files to an SD card, and it is desired to have the filesystem flush to nonvolatile storage as often as reasonable in order to ensure that we have data recorded right up to the moment where power is lost.

I am trying to think of a clever way to test how close my logs approach the moment of lost power.

The system does not have a synchronized clock.  It boots to the beginning of the epoch and does not have a convenient way to synchronize.

Filesystem is UBIFS if that is of interest.  Upvotes for creative simplicity.

Comment: Wouldn't more frequent writes risk burning out the SD card?

Comment: Can you output the logs or timestamps or whatever over the network or a serial connection at the same time the logs are written to the SD card? Then after a power cut you can compare what was on the filesystem with what the remote end received, showing how much was "lost" and did not end up on the filesystem. Also, better check how the filesystem itself handles abrupt power outages...

Comment: @thrig, SD card longevity is not a motivating factor in this system.

Comment: @ikkachu-  Best idea yet.